# Website seamless translation

Tags: php, html, iframe

I'm trying to figure out if there is any way of showing a translated version of a certain website, but keeping the functionality of that website.

Meaning, I do want to 'overlay' the language from the source language to the wanted language, but without modifying the source website. Is that even possible?

A good example was if I could use an iframe, but somehow control the data before it reaches the iframe so I could replace/translate the content.

*(the idea here is not to copy/steal any content from anyone)*

Comment: Google translate does it, it must be possible.

Answer (score 0):

No.. if you want keep the functionalty. A multilanguage site requires db and code ad-hoc.

Rebuilding a website made for only 1 language to support many languages is a big pain

Answer (score 0):

There are two big problems you are going to have to solve:

1. If you downloand the content on your server, translate, then display it - it will be impossible to "keeping the functionality" of the website. Since javascript is, of-course, excecuted on the client side, javascript powered events would still work. However any server-side processing (which is the real power ie: query db, upload, search, etc..) of a web application will be gone because the webpage was not loaded from its origional host.
2. Secondly, if you load the page into the iframe on the client's side you are going to have to deal with the same-domain origin policy. This means that websites/javascript can only manipulate/ajaxify stuff from the same domain as the parent window.

Overcoming both of these problems probably means inventing somesort of new technology and would be a huge time/manpower investment.

*My serious answer is to just accept what google (or other translation services) have to offer.*